# Как сделать отправку формы по клику на чекбокс?

Tags: php

Как сделать, что бы при нажатию на cheackbox шла отправка его в бд о том, что отмечено. Не используя кнопки, а только по нажатию на чекбокс. Какое то наверно свойство внутри нужно прописать. Или лучше использовать для отправки по клику ajax. что бы страница не перегружалась каждый раз

Comment: с помощью php вы никак не отследите клик.

Comment: без js тут впринципе не обойтись, так как это не стандартное поведение элемента

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы отследить клик без JavaScript не обойтись. Вешаем функцию на клик чекбокса, где проверяем на всякий случай выбран ли он, после чего отправляем форму.

```js
function sendForm() {
  if (document.getElementById("myCheckbox").checked) {
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
  }
}
```

```html
<form id='myForm'>
  <input type='checkbox' id='myCheckbox' onclick='sendForm()'
</form>
```